# how to know the main app is running in keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, swiftyuserdefaults

I create a custom keyboard extension of main app. In the extension, i want to know if the main app is running?

Is there any way to make it work?

I have created the app group, and i share data with the UserDefaults

```
var share: UserDefaults? = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.share.keyboard")
```

But i do not know how to realize if the main app is running, please help me, thank you very much! I have search many ways, but not work

Comment: Try save a Bool vale in the User Defaults Group in App Delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @Ridney when  set the bool to false ?

Comment: this is the right place for set the bool at false ---> func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.